# AugluarJS truncating trailing equal sign

Tags: angularjs, url, parameters, base64

AngularJS truncates the trailing equal signs when routing to them. I have a base64 string which need to be added as a query parameter to the url(route)

ex: http://example.com/#!/updatepassword?code=NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==

this loads as:
    http://example.com/#!/updatepassword?code=NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg

Is  there a workaround for this?

Comment: urlencode your parameter value.

Comment: A very good question

Comment: How do you change the route? If you do, for instance `$location.search("code=NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==")`, it will be stripped as you suggest. But if you do `$location.search("code", "NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==");`, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to set route as a string, then you need to escape `=` sign. That's because this character has a special meaning in the query string - it separates parameter name from its value.

So, one solution could be:

```
var query = "code=NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==";
$location.url("/some/path?" + encodeURIComponent(query));
```

What [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) will do, is it will replace all special characters - `=` will be replaced with `%3D` for instance. This will prevent it from being interpreted as a key-value separator.

If you only want to change the query string parameters, not the whole URL, you can also use `$location.search()` method:

```
$location.search("code", "NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==");
```

Just remember to pass two parameters to that method, not one. If you do:

```
$location.search("code=NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg==");
```

the `=` sign will not get escaped, only stripped.

---

Angular uses `parseKeyValue()` function internally to parse query string, it can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/Angular.js#L1056). You can see that the split is being done over the `=` sign. That's why they get stripped.

But if you take a look at [`.search()` method implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ng/location.js#L542), you see that `parseKeyValue()` is being called only if you supply one argument to `.search()`. It's not invoked if you supply name of the parameter as a first, and value as a second argument.

Peeking at the source code also suggests yet another solution:

```
$location.search({"code": "NnuW3q49QW38Mf-Cg=="});
```