# Angular truncating url after "="

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a page where I pass product id from url. This url will be accessed from outside.

Following is my routes definition.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product/:productId', component: ProductComponent }
]
```

In Product component i am subscribing to this consoling the route.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    template: '<h1>Product Page</h1>'
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
            .subscribe(params => {
                console.log(params);
            })
    }
}
```

if access url like `http://localhost:4200/product/Qiqwieqo=s`.

Angular is truncating the url to `http://localhost:4200/product/Qiqwieqo`. And the full param value is not getting consoled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896241/1849366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AugluarJS truncating trailing equal sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894937/augluarjs-truncating-trailing-equal-sign)

Comment: you can use **queryParams** `?Qiqwieqo=5`

Answer (score 0):

Passing the id from url is wrong. The way you are passing is applicable for query params not segment way.There is 2 way you can pass and access query params

```
1) http://localhost:4200/product/Qiqwieqo/s
2) http://localhost:4200/product?Qiqwieqo=s
```